# date with setTimeout - how to reduce time lag in safety way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a big problem with time lag in setTimeout function. I've created code for button show action and I need do that on certain hour. `My problem is that when someone open page about 30 min - 120 min before action without refresh, javascript will do time lag and my action starts much to late.` I need to show that button in very accurate time for everyone - this is reason why I'm using server time (via php) to run script.

Did anyone know how to modify this script to eliminate risk of not showing or to late showing button?

I read about `setTimeout` function lag and I am searching solution for my problem.

I need also to mention that I cant ask server everytime beacause I am expecting about 20k - 30k people online on this event - I've tested that, severs will not survive so many php queries.

My code below:

```
 (function getTime() {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        async:  false,
        url  : 'time.php',
        success : function(response){

            // date of button display

            var year = "2017",
                month = "03",
                day = "10",
                hour = "14",
                minute = "21",
                second = "21";

            var startDate = new Date("" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second +"+01:00"); 

            // +01:00 timezone correction

            var buttonTime = startDate.getTime() / 1000; // time - when display button

            var currentTime = response;


            (function testTime() {

                 var diff = buttonTime - currentTime;

                if (currentTime > buttonTime ) {
                    // triggers here"

                    alert(' here will be trigger of show button');

                }

                if (currentTime <= buttonTime && diff <= 60 ) {
                    // test after 1 s.

                     var testDelay = 1000;
                     currentTime = parseInt(currentTime) + 1;
                     console.log(currentTime);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        testTime();
                    }, testDelay);
                }

                if (currentTime < buttonTime && diff > 60 ) {
                    // test after 10s.

                    var testDelay = 10000;
                    currentTime = parseInt(currentTime) + 10; 
                    console.log(currentTime);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        testTime(); 
                    }, testDelay);

                } 

            })();

        },
        complete(){},
        error(){}
    });

})();
```

and php for this:

```
<?php 

$timestamp = time();
echo $timestamp;

?>
```

Comment: I suppose you realise `$date_time = date($timestamp);` does nothing

Comment: I've tested that, it's true, but it not solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve problem. Result is below :) I compare server time nad user hardware time and add difference to button show time. :)

```
    function getTime() {

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            async:  false,
            url  : 'time.php',
            success : function(response){

                // date of button display

                var year = "2017",
                    month = "03",
                    day = "22",
                    hour = "13",
                    minute = "50",
                    second = "01";

                var startDate = new Date("" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second +"+01:00"); 

                // +01:00 timezone correction

                var buttonTime = startDate.getTime() / 1000; // time - when display button

                var currentTime = parseInt(response);

                if (!Date.now) {
                  Date.now = function now() {
                    return new Date().getTime() / 1000;
                  };
                }

                var userPcTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

                if (currentTime !== userPcTime) {

                    var timeDiff = currentTime - userPcTime;

                    buttonTime = buttonTime - timeDiff;

                    console.log(timeDiff);
                }

                function testTime() {

                    if (!Date.now) {
                      Date.now = function now() {
                        return new Date().getTime() / 1000;
                      };
                    }

                    var userPcTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

                     var diff = buttonTime - userPcTime;



                    if (userPcTime > buttonTime ) {
                        // triggers here"

                        alert(' here will be trigger of show button');

                    }

                    if (userPcTime <= buttonTime && diff <= 60 ) {

                        // test after 1 s.

                         var testDelay = 1000;

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            testTime();
                        }, testDelay);
                    }

                    if (userPcTime < buttonTime && diff > 60 ) {
                        // test after 10 s.

                        var testDelay = 10000;

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            testTime(); 
                        }, testDelay);

                    } 

                };

                testTime();

            },
            complete(){},
            error(){}
        });

    };

getTime();
```

And correct time.php is:

```
<?php 

$timestamp = time();
$date_time = date($timestamp);
echo $date_time;

?>
```